# How to get average of all nonzero values in Room db without spoiling sum of other values?

Tags: android, sql, database, android-room

I have a table with rows val1 and val2 (both numbers).

I need to SELECT `SUM` of val1 but `AVG` of a second. The issue is that in case that the val2 is 0 it shouldn't be counted in the val2 average, but it still should be in the val1 sum.

Example table:

| id | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 4 |

For this table, I would like to get a result `3 + 2 + 1 = 6` for val1, but `2 + 4 / 2 = 3` for the val2

**I also need to do only one SELECT query because of performance.**

I think I there should be some simple condition like this one:

```
SELECT SUM(val1) as val1, AVG(IF val2 > 0) as val2 FROM Table
```

But it IF doesn't exists here. I didn't find any documentation for these queries in zoom.

EDIT:
I am trying to use `CASE`, but apparently not right…

```
SELECT SUM(val1) as val1, AVG(CASE (val2 when val2 > 0 THEN  val2)) as val2 FROM Table
```

Comment: `AVG(CASE when val2 <> 0 then val2 end)`

Comment: This is what happens if you are afraid of using NULL values, and instead has 0.

Comment: @jarlh cool, thanks, will try. Actually, it didn't even occur to me to use null (probably Kotlin influence). But that is actually not a bad solution for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest method is `NULLIF()`:

```
SELECT SUM(val1) as val1,
       AVG(NULLIF(val2, 0)) as val2
FROM Table;
```

`NULLIF()` is a Standard SQL function that returns `NULL` when the first argument matches the value in the second argument.